# XSLT Transformation to replace element on web.config

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

Could someone please help me to understand the XSLT below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically I would like to apply an XSLt transformation to remove the element below from web.config:

```
<system.net>
      <defaultProxy>
         <proxy
            usesystemdefault = "false"
            proxyaddress="http://proxyserver"
            bypassonlocal="true"
         />
      </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the standard form of the "identity" template, which copies its input to output unchanged - it works by matching any node (`@*` matches attributes, `node()` matches everything else), making a shallow copy of that node, and then recursively applying templates to attributes and children of the node it has just shallow-copied.  You can override this behaviour for specific nodes by adding other templates, which will take priority over the identity template.  For example, to remove all `system.net` elements you could add

```
<xsl:template match="system.net" />
```

(i.e. "when you see a `system.net` element, do nothing").  The complete transformation to remove all `system.net` elements would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="system.net" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I remove after match is found?

Comment: @Myagdi I've added the complete example to make it clearer what I mean - this transformation would copy all nodes from the input to the output _except_ elements named `system.net`.